# Why is there a sync with oldest profile link on my Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support, profile-sync, synchronization

When I created a Stack Exchange account there was an option which offered to link my profiles on the various sites. I did and now I see all my accounts on Stack Exchange.

But why is there a "sync with oldest profile" on my account page? I assumed after the merge I had linked all the accounts, so I have a common account which is kept automatically in sync across sites. What does the manual syncing link does then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This serves two purposes.

1. It tells you which profile is driving your network account.
2. That's actually a link to perform a sync.  Your network profile will sync daily, but you can also have it do a manual sync if you change your data and want it updated sooner than the daily process.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had to push that link regularly to keep the accounts in sync. Maybe the wording should be more descripitve, "sync now if you don't want to wait for automatic sync" or something like that